# Accessing view from a controller class

Tags: c#

Is it possible to access the view(Form in my case) from the controller class without any scripting in the view's codebehind file?

Comment: tell, dont ask works well in mvc scenarios, so why do you want to do that?

Comment: What exactly are you looking to do with the View?

Comment: subscribe the UI control events from the controller

Comment: This breaks the MVC paradigm, which is why it is inherently difficult to do. Your view should be very stupid, and the controller should be providing it everything it needs to know through the Model/ViewData.

Comment: Thanks, I see MVC projects handling the event[eg:-button click,etc] inside the view's codebehind and then calling controller. Wouldn't that make view less stupid? I was trying to move all the handling mecahism to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

MVC isn't following the same paradigm as WebForms - that's the point! JavaScript is likely your friend here, and for dynamic interaction on pages, AJAX as well.